# Stream from Realtime Firebase DB to BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-bigquery

Is there any extention or ways to stream data from Realtime Firebase DB to BigQuery? I have read about [Stream Collections to BigQuery](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-firestore-bigquery-export) but the description said it can be from Cloud Firestore

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. Is there a way to send data from the realtime database to a collection, and then make use of the Stream Firestore to BigQuery extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There is currently no Firebase Extension for streaming data from the Realtime Database to BigQuery. It is being considered though, so I [file a or feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report) with our support team to express your interest in that.

But for the moment you will have to implement the functionality yourself, likely with Cloud Functions listening to changes in the Realtime Database and then calling the BigQuery API to insert the data there. Given that Extensions are open-source by definition, you could use the [source of the <kbd>Stream Collections to BigQuery</kbd>](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/tree/master/firestore-bigquery-export) as a template/for inspiration.